# Jquery class selector is not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

I have following html tags.

```
<span class="ui-btn-text">ALFL</span>
<span class="ui-btn-text">AL</span>
```

I want to replace ALFL with

```
<span class="ui-btn-text">A</span>
```

through jquery.

I have used

```
$("span .ui-btn-text").replaceWith("<span class="ui-btn-text">A</span>");
```

But it is not working. Please give me some answers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the **ALFL** Text , you can do something like this :

```
var $span= $('span.ui-btn-text');
$span.each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() =='ALFL') {
        $(this).text('A');
    }        
});
```

Js fiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/95CyN/

If you want to change text/html of all span with class ui-btn-text, do this:

```
 // change the text inside the element
 $('span.ui-btn-text').text('A');
```

OR

```
 // change the html content inside the element
 $('span.ui-btn-text').html('A');
```

OR

```
  // Replace the html element
  $('span.ui-btn-text').replaceWith('<span class="ui-btn-text">A</span>');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answers. Its very help ful.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector matches an element that has the class `ui-btn-text` with a parent that is a `span`. You just need to remove the space.

I also noticed that your `replaceWith` replaces the element with a duplicate of itself with some content. There's no need to replace the element, just set the text:

```
$("span.ui-btn-text").text("A");
```

Answer (score 1):

What's about

`$("span.ui-btn-text").replaceWith("<span class='ui-btn-text'>A</span>");`

or

```
$("span.ui-btn-text").text("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is looking for an element with the class of `.ui-btn-next` inside a `span` element, because you includied a superfluous space character:

```
$("span.ui-btn-text").replaceWith("<span class="ui-btn-text">A</span>");
```

Should be what you want. Also, if you only need to change the content of the element (i.e. to "A"), use `text()` or `html()`:

```
$("span.ui-btn-text").text('A');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span.ui-btn-text").replaceWith('<span class="ui-btn-text">A</span>');
```

The replacement string you wrote is going to make the Javascript engine crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code friend:-

 $("span.ui-btn-text").each(function () {                   
                if ($(this).html() == "ALFL") {
                    $(this).html("A");
                }
            });
        });
```